# organizational units get list of enabled services

Tags: java, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

I'm looking for a way to retrieve a list of Google Apps enabled (disabled) services.
The services I'm interested in are: Calendar, Contacts, Drive, Mail.
When running a backup of these services I get errors when they are disabled. So my solution is check if they are enabled, than backup, others ignore it.

I'm able to work with the Api's (Service account).
I tried Directory api but I can only get basic organizational unit info.

Thank you

*I've been looking for a solution but can not find any. This is the last part of my schools internship project.*

edit1: typo

Comment: Please post some code or what you have done.

Comment: @asokBuzz I'm looking for an api call. There is nothing wrong with my  code that should come after this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API call to determine which services are on/off for an OU or a user. Instead, you should be catching the error which occurs when the service is disabled for the user, logging it, and moving on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought this was the case but this is not the most elegant way(forcing error than catch). But if it is the only way. Google should open there api ...